# PHP Regular Expressions: How to write rules

Tags: php, regex

How do I validate a string against the following rules:

```
$string = 'int(11)';

Rule: first 4 characters MUST be 'int('
Rule: next must be a number between 1 and 11
Rule: next must be a ')'
Rule: Everything else will fail
```

Experienced PHP Developer here - Regular Expressions are not my strong point..

Any help or suggestions welcome.
Thanks guys..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/int\((\d{1,2})\)/', $str, $matches)
    && (int) $matches[1] <= 11 && (int) $matches[1] > 0
   ) {
    // ... do something nice
} else {
    echo 'Failed!!!'
}
```

Or if you want to not use the pReg library (can be faster):

```
$str = 'int(11)';
$i = substr($str, 4, strpos($str, ')') - 4);

if (substr($str, 0, 4) === 'int('
    && $i <= 11
    && $i > 0
   ) {
    echo 'succes';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: +1 but Syntax error - `=<` should be `<=`...

Answer (score 4):

use this regular expression `int\((\d|1[01])\)`

`int\((` first rule

`(\d|1[01])` second rule

`\)` third rule

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression is even smaller:

```
int\((\d1?)\)
```

or without the capturing group (if you don't need to retrieve the numeric value).

```
int\(\d1?\)
```